# Is transport encryption useless, if end-to-end encryption is used?

Tags: encryption, end-to-end-encryption

Does it have any advantages to do transport-encryption for messages that are already end-to-end encrypted?

Comment: there could be unprotected e2e meta that would be covered by the transport. unless you need top perf, it doesn't hurt anything to have more layers of protection.

Comment: It's a matter of how you define the 'transport' and the 'end points'.  Right now, I have transport encryption from my web browser to security.stackexchange.com (as I can see by the padlock that appears in my web browser's address bar).  This means that information is encrypted end-to-end from my web browser to the server for security.stackexchange.com.  So, in this case, the two are one in the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## No, it's not useless.

Transport encryption may hide details about the application protocol being used. For example, if a TLS handshake between Alice and Bob is being recorded, and then some data is being transfered, then the attacker can really not see what *kind* of data is being transferred.<sup>1</sup>

On the contrary, if an application-specific protocol, such as the [Signal Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_Protocol), is being used, then at attacker gets the information about what kind of communication is happening.

#### Is this a big deal?

That depends on your threat model!

Imagine you are a journalist in an oppressive regime, and being watched 24/7. Outgoing Signal data at a specific time may be enough metadata for them to arrest you, while a "regular" TLS connection may not be.

If this seems far-fetched for you, then you got a perfect example of how different people have different threat models. Perhaps leaking this metadata is fine for you, in which case "just" having End-to-End encryption on an application level is fine (assuming it's implemented securely).

---

<sup>1</sup> This is not entirely true. Certain tranmission patters, such as "bursting", may allow an attacker to determine what kind of data is being transmitted (e.g. a video stream), which may already be enough.

Comment: It should also be noted that transport encryption may still save your butt if your End-to-End Encryption protocol turns out to be flawed. I didn't include this in the answer, as I assumed the End-to-End encryption to be solid, but in case it isn't, keep that in mind.